# How to FIND the limit of a sequence with epsilon definition?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

So I have this sequence in hand: $x_n=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}$, and I can intuitively see that its limit as $n\to\infty$ is 0, and I can verify it with the $\varepsilon$ definition of the limit. But I am asked to FIND this limit with only the epsilon definition of the limit, how can I do that? (I can only find the limit by manipulating the statement into $\sqrt{\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{1}{n+2+\frac{1}{n}}}}$)

Comment: The $\epsilon$-$N$ definition of  limit is not a tool for *finding* the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any $\epsilon > 0$,

$$|x_n-0|=\left| \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1} - 0\right| <  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < \epsilon,$$

if $n > 1/ \epsilon^2.$

Hence $x_n \rightarrow 0$ and a limit when it exists is unique.

Comment: So the idea is to guess a limit then check it? Is there a way to find the limit without guessing first?

Comment: It isn't exactly a guess if you consider it to be a derivation based on the assumption that the limit exists. So I guess a formal proof would involve first proving that the sequence converges, which then justifies the derivation of the limit. Alternatively you could consider it a guess, which you are then using to prove that the limit both exists and is equal to 0, in one step. At least that is my understanding